# UICollectionViewCells aren't displaying content correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a two `ViewControllers`, and each one of them has a collectionView *(let's name it CV)*.

The first CV Cell *(named MainPageCell)* is the main structure of the app, and among it's other components, it displays an UIView named `imageViewGrid`.

The purpose of the second controller is only to add it's CV to itself as a subview, and then, it can be **added as a child** of the first controller and then **insert it's view on the imageViewGrid**.

In a nutshell, **I'm trying to display a CV inside of another CV component**. But the cells of the second CV doesn't load, or if they do, **they disappear when scrolling**. Just one cell can display the content until I scroll.

This GIF describes my situation: [Click here](https://i.gyazo.com/72e848d4f690a4036724563866eeb80e.mp4)

**First CV cellForItemAt:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: mainReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MainPageCell
        
    displayController(contentController: photoGridController, on: cell.imageViewGrid)
    
    return cell
}
```

**imageViewGrid declaration inside MainPageCell:**

```
    var imageViewGrid: UIView = {
    let ivg = UIView()
    ivg.backgroundColor = Colors.lightBlue
    ivg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return ivg
}()
```

**DisplayController func:**

```
func displayController(contentController content: UIViewController, on view: UIView) {
    addChild(content)
    view.addSubview(content.view)
    content.view.frame = view.bounds
    content.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

**Second CV cellForItemAt:**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: photoReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotoGridCell
    
    cell.backgroundColor = Colors.lightBlue
    cell.item = names[indexPath.item]
    
    return cell
}
```

**Second CV cell components:**

```
    var item: String? {
    didSet {
        guard let myItem = item,
              let image = UIImage(named: myItem) else { return }
        
        if image == UIImage(named: myItem) {
            gridImageView.image = image
        } else {
            gridImageView.image = UIImage(named: "fbicon")
        }
    }
}

let gridImageView: UIImageView = {
   let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return iv
}()
```

**I don't know if I'm supposed to reload something, or if I forget a step, but couldn't been able to make this work, yet. I'd appreciate some help.**

Comment: It will be very difficult for anyone to help with only this information. Try creating a [mre] (post it on GitHub or somewhere similar). Also, it's not a good idea to post duplicate questions here...

Comment: So if I understand correctly you have a main VC managing a UICollectionView and every cell has Viewcontroller embedded into them?

Comment: @LucaSfragara Each VC has a collectonView. The first controller is like the parent, and it's custom cell has a UIView. The second controller's view is added on the previous mentioned UIView, and there's the problem: it doesn't load the content on that cell, but the other elements of the first controller works just fine.